# JPA-HIBERNATE : How to select the key/value of a map attribute using KEY /VALUE syntax with JPQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have the following entities with correspondent getters/setters:

```
@Entity
public class Movie {
   @Id@GeneratedValue 
   private int id;
       private String title;   
//getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class VideoStore {

  @Id@GeneratedValue
  private int id;
  private String name;

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name="INVENTORY",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="STORE_ID"))
  @Column(name="COPIES_IN_STOCK")
  @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="MOVIE",referencedColumnName="ID")
  Map<Movie,Integer>videoInventory;
//getters and setters
}
```

From a main method I am trying to perform the following JPQL query:

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Tutorial");
    EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();
    String queryMap1 = "SELECT v " +
            "FROM VideoStore v JOIN v.videoInventory m " +
            "WHERE KEY(m) = 1";
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    List results= em.createQuery(queryMap1).getResultList();
```

I am getting the following error:

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'KEY(videoinven1_.COPIES_IN_STOCK)=1' at line 1

Also I am getting different types of errors with every variation of the query that contains KEY/VALUE/ENTRY syntax

I am using JPA with Hibernate and Mysql as database provider.I couldn't find an answer to this problem so I would appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you compare the return value of `KEY(m)` (which is a `Movie`) with a number.